# ES6 arrow losing enclosing scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hi I was under the impression that if you use a arrow function, this refers to the enclosing scope as explained on the following link

https://www.sitepoint.com/bind-javascripts-this-keyword-react/:

> 4. ES2015 Arrows
>
> The ES2015 specification introduces the arrow function syntax for
>   writing function expressions. As well as being terser than regular
>   function expressions, they can also have implicit return and most
>   importantly, they always use the value of this from the enclosing
>   scope.

In the example below `this` does not refer the the enclosing scope rather refers to the global scope.

```
addMeasurement(username,jsonObject){
    ...
    return fetch(measurementURL,
    {
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: jsonStringify
    }).then( (res) => { 
        // this below refers to the global context. 
        //Instead of the current instance and hence is undefined
        this.addMeasurementToAudit(username,jsonObject)             
        res.json() 
    });
}
```

Without arrow and explicitly binding this,works as expected:

```
addMeasurement(username,jsonObject){
    ...
    return fetch(measurementURL,
    {
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: jsonStringify
    }).then( function success(res) { 
        //this refers to the enclosing instance and works as expected
        this.addMeasurementToAudit(username,jsonObject)
        res.json() 
    }.bind(this));
},
```

Comment: before the return statement inside `addMeasurement`, what does `this` refer to?

Comment: Is this the *exact* code? If so & the latter works, the former should definitely work. How is `addMeasurement` called & defined? Is it in a class or object?

Comment: @MauricioPoppe it refers to the the enclosing context ...e.g. the current instance

Comment: @RGraham here is the full function: http://pastebin.com/VkPurviW

Comment: @ShivamSinha That's not the full function because there is no enclosing scope to look at, nor does it show how `addMeasurement` is called. The trailing `,` makes me think it's an object but might not be. Not that it should make a difference but might make it easier to reproduce your issue

Comment: @RGraham Here is more context to the question my MeasurementDAO..js addMeasurement calls -- > FirebaseRESTUtil.js .addMeasuement . I am using react native. http://pastebin.com/cK1BaFET

Comment: This has nothing to do with arrows, because you have to use bind along with the normal function expression anyway

Comment: @ShivamSinha: That pastebin code is not the one you've shown here. `addMeasurementToLocal` is a function call not a method invocation, and something like that will be your problem. Also in `FirebaseRESTUtil.addMeasurement`  you did *not* use an arrow function.

Comment: IMO this should closed as not reproducible or as a duplicate of  [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196).

Comment: @Bergi yes that's because I replaced it with the success function which I described in the question. Also the question has both versions of the method including the fat arrow one.

Comment: @FelixKling it is not a duplicate of that question...let me know if you want me to clarify any part of my question. I will attempt to provide reproducible results when I get the chance.

Comment: The only reason why `this` wouldn't refer to the instance is if you don't call `addMeasurement` as a method of the instance. But if it works with `.bind` then the environment you are running the code in has a bug (and there is nothing we can do to fix that).

Comment: @FelixKling Agreed. I'll attempt provide reproducible results within the next 24hrs.

Comment: @FelixKling I was attempting to demo the problem on https://rnplay.org/ ...however they seem to have some issues right now. So instead I created two video 1. working https://vid.me/eokG  2. not working https://vid.me/n9GM with fat arrow.